# Flutter ARKit Video Node

Tags: flutter, dart, arkit, videodisplay

**My problem:**

I work with Flutter and use the ARKit plugin.

The flutter arkit plugin is very extensive, but I can't find anything about **how to display an AR video.**

has this not yet been implemented in the ARKIT plugin?
**Plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin**

i already googled but i can't find anyone who has the same problem.

all the examples i can find are written in swift.
Example:
**https://medium.com/quick-code/using-arkit-to-display-video-in-augmented-reality-3a2e4c1418ad**

**Does anyone have a solution for me?**

Do I have to create a channel for the swift code?

**Thanks for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

add the video to folder ios/Runner

```
ARKitNode _createVideo() {
final _video = ARKitMaterialProperty.video(
  width: 406,
  height: 720,
  filename: 'myvideo.mp4',
);
final material = ARKitMaterial(
  diffuse: _video,
  doubleSided: true,
);

final plane = ARKitPlane(
  width: 1,
  height: 1,
  materials: [material],
);
return ARKitNode(
  geometry: plane,
  position: vector.Vector3(0, -.7, -.3),
  eulerAngles: vector.Vector3(360, 360, 360),
  name: 'my video',
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 final   _video = ARKitMaterialProperty.video(
        url: 'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4',
        width: 640,
        height: 320,
        autoplay: true,
        //  filename: 'london.mp4',
      );

      final material = ARKitMaterial(
        diffuse: _video,
        doubleSided: true,
      );

  final plane = ARKitPlane(
        width: 0.5,
        height: 0.3,
        materials: [material],
      );

      final earthPosition = anchor.transform.getColumn(3);
      final node = ARKitNode(
        geometry: plane,
        position: vector.Vector3(earthPosition.x, earthPosition.y, earthPosition.z),
        eulerAngles: vector.Vector3(0, 0,0),
      );


      arkitController.add(node);
```